# Are {layout:set} variables available to all extended layouts?

Tags: variable, template-layouts

I'm trying to make sure I understand the scope of {layout:set} variables, compared to how embeds work.

Traditionally, variables set with an `{embed="template_group/template variable="foo"}` are only accessible one level deep, directly within the embedded template.

**Now let's talk layouts.**

We have at minimum 2 layout templates: `layouts/global` & `layouts/master`.

For the sake of this questions, let's say I have a `blog/index` template that extends `layouts/master` and `layouts/master` extends `layouts/global`

**blog/index:**

```
 {layout="layouts/master"}

 {layout:set name="title"}Blog Title | {site_name}{/layout:set}

    {exp:channel:entries channel="blog"}

        All the blog content here...

    {/exp:channel:entries}
```

**layouts/master:**

```
{layout="layouts/global"}

{embed="embeds/masthead"}

{layout:contents}

{embed="embeds/footer"}
```

**layouts/global:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{layout:title}</title>
    </head>

     <body>   

         {layout:contents}

    </body>
</html>
```

The question I'd like clarity on (that my tests confirm) is this: Will the the {layout:title} variable be available within the `layouts/global` template regardless of where it's set, or do I have to redefine it within the `layouts/master` template, the way that you have to do if you were nesting embeds and passing variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my own testing, the value set for the `{layout:title}` variable will cascade back through the layout templates to the outermost layout. So if you set it in a nested template or a template that ultimately uses the global layout, then the value of the variable will be available to the global layout.

If you set the `{layout:title}` variable in a nested template (e.g. `blog/index` in your example) then redefine it in the `layouts/master` template, the value set in `layouts/master` template will be the one that is presented to the global layout.

Note that you can use this to extend the value of the variable like this:

**blog/index :**

```
{layout="layouts/master"}

{layout:set name="title"}Blog Title{/layout:set}

{exp:channel:entries channel="blog"}

    All the blog content here...

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

**layouts/master :**

```
{layout="layouts/global"}

{layout:set name="title"}{layout:title} | {site_name}{/layout:set}

{embed="embeds/masthead"}

{layout:contents}

{embed="embeds/footer"}
```

**layouts/global :**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>{layout:title}</title>
  </head>

   <body>   

     {layout:contents}

  </body>
</html>
```

would result in the following:

```
    <title>Blog Title | Site Name</title>
```